# Get arguments in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a programming language and I'm trying to implement command line arguments for when you run the program. When you open the program file it uses a batch file called `start.bat`

`start.bat`:

```
@echo off
set FILE=%1

cd %~dp0
title AtomScript - %FILE%
java -jar AtomScript.jar %FILE%
```

Also. I understand that when making an interpreted language, C or C++ is recommended. I'm using java to prototype it.

Okay. So my problem is I want to run the program with arguments like so:
`C:/Users/User/Programs>main.atom arg1 arg2 arg3`

The program then should print:

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

My question is, how do I get those arguments from the command line in a batch script?

Comment: If your question is only about the batchfile, please remove the unnecessary tags.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but START is a standard internal command. You should never name a batch script the same as an existing command, else you are asking for trouble. I recommend something like startAtomScript.bat instead.

Answer (score 0):

`%1` expands to the first command line parameter, `%2` ... `%9` to 2nd-9th accordingly.

You can also pass the entire command line with `%*`:

```
java -jar AtomScript.jar %*
```

[More info](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: It seems that it still does't get the arguments. I tried running the `.atom` file with arguments. But it still didn't pass it.

Comment: It seems there's something you didn't tell us because this code works, for example, if you put the code to a `.bat` file, which is executed like `mybatchfile param1 param2 param3` or `cmd /c mybatchfile param1 param2 param3`.

Comment: It works when I do `start.bat dir/to/main.atom arg1 arg2 arg3` but when I just call `main.atom arg1 arg2 arg3` it doesn't work.

Comment: `main.atom arg1 arg2 arg3` never executes the batch file, so, of course, the batch file will never do anything. There's some misunderstanding apparently.

Comment: Actually. `main.atom` alone executes the batch file. But when I add the arguments, the arguments aren't passed through.

Comment: Well, apparently, `main.atom` doesn't pass the arguments to the batch file. Maybe you'll post the relevant part of the code?

Comment: `.atom` files open with the `start.bat` file. `start.bat` is the default program selected to run the `.atom` files.